# Java Generic Array Runtime Initialize error

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have created generic array but constructor can not initialize the array. When runtime program throws this exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
 Uncompilable source code - generic array creation
```

how to initialize generic array properly.

```
class MyList<K,V>{
    K[] k;
    V[] v;
public MyList() {
    k = new K[0];
    v = new V[0];
}

public void add(K key, V val){
    Object[] ob1 = new Object[k.length+1];
    Object[] ob2 = new Object[v.length+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
        ob1[i]=k[i];
        ob2[i]=v[i];
    }
    ob1[k.length]=key;
    ob2[v.length]=val;

    k=(K[]) ob1;
    v=(V[]) ob2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyList<Integer,Double> values = new MyList<>();
    values.add(1,0.5);
}
}
```

why this happen, is there solution?

Comment: Can't you use a Map (HashMap) for this purpose instead of implementing a new generic array?

Comment: Classic question to differentiate between C++ and Java programmer: Is it possible to write `K k = new K()` in template/generics context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Constructor

```
public MyList(K[] k, V[] v) {
    this.k = k;
    this.v = v;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyList<Integer,Double> values = new MyList<>(new Integer[0], new Double[0]);
    values.add(1,0.5);
}
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are reifiable types , means there type information should be maintained at runtime.

```
 k = new K[0];
 v = new V[0];
```

here, since `K` and `V` are generic parameters , type erasure will kick in and erase them to `Object`.

use `newInstance()` method in `Array` class to create generic arrays.